# client closed prematurely connection while sending to client, in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have error in nginx error.log:

```
2010/12/05 17:11:49 [info] 7736#0: *1108 client closed prematurely connection while sending to client, 
client: 188.72.80.201, server:***.biz, request: "GET /forum/ HTTP/1.1", 
upstream:"http://***:3000/forum/", host: "***.biz"
```

I have 500 response code on site everytime. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Maybe this help: None of the answers worked for me. I switched to another computer and tried to access the HTTPS address and it worked. The issue is either client side or something cached on the server.

Comment: I've found that this error was very misleading. I installed Apache HTTPd smoke out the issue, and sure enough, I received similar errors in apache. However, apache errors were a bit more definitive with "[Sun Apr 29 10:44:20.575666 2018] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 11342:tid 139630102398720] event.c(1123): (32)Broken pipe: [client 192.168.1.1:60708] AH00470: network write failure in core output filter" Which pointed me to reviewing my router, which turned out to be the problem. Captured the logs and documented the issue on my blog: https://swazzy.com/2018/04/29/evasive-errors/

Answer (score 22):

Setting [proxy_ignore_client_abort on;](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort) might help you.

Comment: this did it for me

Comment: this works for me as well. Thumbs Up. Remember to set it inside the http block under /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. Cant make it work when put it under server block

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this would fix it?

Comment: Yes, worked for me as well. Also thanks to Danny Teo for the proper placement!

Comment: from the docs: determines whether the connection with a proxied server should be closed when a client closes the connection without waiting for a response https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort

Answer (score 18):

I tackled this problem myself for long hours today and found a solution:
**Please note that this fix only affects you when using load balancer(s)**

Check your load balancer idle timeout. I had ELB idle timeout set to 60 seconds (default) and as the request was hanging, it closed the connection after given time. But as the ELB is before nginx, nginx is logging that the "client" (in this case ELB), is closing the connection.

So if you are using ELB, go to:
**EC2 -> Load Balancers -> Select the correct one -> scroll down in description and change Idle Timeout** if you are using other load balancers, check their configuration and timeouts.

Also keep in mind that you still might be needing to change the proxy timeouts etc.

Comment: Also check for the target configuration if you have EC2 -> Target Groups -> Select the correct one -> scroll down -> Health Check -> Change the Timeout property.

Answer (score 7):

I found that if you turn off the proxy buffer helps

```
http {
   proxy_buffering off;
...
}
```

Probably the buffers are too small or less.
After changing the buffer sizes it works nice

```
proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffer_size 8k;
proxy_buffers 2048 8k;
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and researched on it. In my case this only happens with Webkit (Chrome) browsers. They open connections optimistically more connections than they require if you only load a single resource. In such a case, the excess connection is closed ungracefully or at least without sending any HTTP verb over it. This leads to the mentioned error in nginx.

Regarding #1 answer:
Non of  the proposed solutions help which is logical as this has nothing to do with proxying.

Regarding #2 answer:
proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
Does **not** help in my test.

Unfortunately, I've found no other solution than using

error_log off;

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, found that nginx closes the connection because of send_timeout setting. I increased and it is fixed.

```
http
{
send_timeout 20;
...
}
```

Comment: ...but the default is actually 60 seconds: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#send_timeout

Answer (score -3):

`fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on` will definitely solve the issue.

Comment: explain your answer briefly. where OP need to set it etc., so that it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: Yes an explanation would be helpful.